# Remove dependency from package.json

Tags: laravel

I want to remove a specific dependency from my package.json file in laravel. I want to remove     `"laravel-elixir-webpack": "^1.0.1"` from my app. How to do it ?

Comment: Careful @recoverymen, composer is for PHP libraries (not JavaScript libraries)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manually remove that line from your package.json, then run `npm update`. Or simply

```
npm uninstall laravel-elixir-webpack
```

Comment: Ahh. didn't have time to check the documentation. thanks

Comment: I guess another alternative is `yarn remove {package name}` (but not as compatible since it requires yarn to be installed)

Comment: i only installed npm not yarn  :)

Comment: @A.Sand please don't forget to mark the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks :)